# Error while reading wav file: wave.Error: unknown format: 6

Tags: python, wav

I want to convert a wav file to text.
While reading the wav file I found the following error:
Code

```
import wave,struct
wavefile=wave.open('C:/Users/SA769740/Desktop/task4/test.wav','r')
```

the error:

```
raise Error('unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,))
wave.Error: unknown format: 6
```

what are the possible reasons?

Comment: @renemilk can you please elaborate what are you want to say?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer. The wave lib only reads a very specific type of wave, whose ID is not 6.

Comment: @renemilk can you give me any idea how to fix that issue? I tried but not found a good way to change the format of the wav file to readable format

Comment: You should update your question with what you now tried and where what failed.

Comment: Audacity is not a permissible software in my lab.

Comment: You should better describe your problem and restrictions in your question then. It's useless for us to guess.